# htaccess: check for string in url, and redirect to the same url without that string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My site's current url structure is something like that:

```
http://www.example.com/en-US/foo/bar 
http://www.example.com/es-ES/baz
http://www.example.com/fr-FR/1/2/3
```

Now I need to remove the language part and redirect the urls to:

```
http://www.example.com/foo/bar 
http://www.example.com/baz
http://www.example.com/1/2/3
```

So, basically I need to check if my url contains a lang code (en-US, fr-FR, es-ES...) and, if it does, redirect to the same url WITHOUT that lang code.
How can I do that using htaccess?

This is my current htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(admin)($|/) - [L]

# redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect from .com to .co.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/homepage$ /pages/index.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/404$ /pages/404.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/contents/register$ /pages/registrazione.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/contents/account$ /pages/account.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/info/(.*)$ /pages/$2.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/search$ /pages/risultati-ricerca.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/shop/(.*)/(.*) /pages/dettaglio-articolo.php?lang=$1&coll=2&slug=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/store/(.*)/([1-3]+)/(.*)/(.*) /pages/dettaglio-articolo.php?lang=$1&coll=2&num_cat=$3&cat=$4&slug=$5 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/store/shoppingcart$ /pages/carrello.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/store/login /pages/login.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/store/forgot$ /pages/forgot.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/store/register /pages/registrazione.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/buy/checkout /pages/ordine_indirizzo.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/buy/payment /pages/ordine_pagamento.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/buy/confirm /pages/ordine_conferma.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/buy/order-confirm-ko$ /pages/ordine_conferma-pagamento.php?lang=$1&result=ko [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/buy/order-confirm$ /pages/ordine_conferma-pagamento.php?lang=$1&result=ok [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What are your current rules? Add them to your question

Comment: Sorry, added...